# Making Cell Appear When Calling Range.Select() in Office.js API

Tags: javascript, excel, reactjs, office-js

I'm using React.js in a javascript Office Add-in.  In Desktop Excel, when the user selects a record in the Add-In pane, we use the code below to select the cell (range).

The cell receives focus and in a multi-sheet Excel workbook, the proper worksheet is selected.  However, the selected cell does not come into view for the user.  In other words, the worksheet doesn't scroll to the selected cell.

Is there a better way to do this?

```
showNoteRequested({ context }) {
  const { note } = context;
  note.tags.forEach((tag) => {
    if (tag.name.indexOf('SymphonyBinding_') !== -1) {
      this.setState({ bindingName: tag.name }, this.selectRange);
    }
  });
}

selectRange() {
  const { bindingName } = this.state;
  try {
    Excel.run((ctx) => {
      const foundBinding = ctx.workbook.bindings.getItem(bindingName);
      const myRange = foundBinding.getRange();
      myRange.select();
      myRange.load('address');
      return ctx.sync().then(() => {
        const currentAddress = myRange.address;
        this.setState({ currentAddress });
      });
    });
  } catch (error) {
    handleError('Office Add-In', error, error.message);
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you may be looking for the `.visible` property?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-visible-property-excel  We also know that CTRL+End or CTRL+Right or Left or Home will navigate to the last row of a pre-poulated sheet.

Comment: Thank you Leptonator, but we are using the Office.js javascript api for Office.  There doesn't appear to be an equivalent command.

Answer (score 1):

The range.select() should activate the worksheet and take the selection and view to the selected cell(s). The view may happen to be at the bottom-right corner of the screen depending on how far it is from the top-left corner. That's just the default behavior of Excel app... but the view should scroll down/right to the selected cells. I'm testing on the latest Office build and it seems to be working fine. 
Which Office build are you using? After the API call, if you press arrow keys, what does the view show?

```
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {
// Selecting a cell that is way down below the normal view. This API call does scroll the view from any worksheet down to selected range.
        const range = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem('Sheet2').getRange('Z300');       
        range.select();

    });
```

Comment: Hi Sudhi.  It works in Excel Online, but doesn't work in Excel Desktop.  The cell gets selected, and the worksheet tab gets selected, but the cell does not come into view.  No "scrolling" happens at all.  If the user hits an arrow key, it does bring the cell into view.  That's something we will bring up to our users, but not ideal.

Comment: Agree that's not the experience you want. Given that I cannot re-pro the error could you let us know which build you are working on? Are you on O365 version, which build#?

Comment: Sudhi, we are using Excel 2016 MSO (16.0.4639.1000) 32-bit

Comment: This is the MSI version. There may be an issue with this version. Will get back with an update.

Comment: @SudhiRamamurthy - Any luck? Four years later, I'm being hit by the same thing. `select` doesn't scroll the range into view on Desktop Excel.

Comment: @CoryL - Did you ever find a way to get Desktop Excel to behave?